# What is the difference between .DictWriter() vs .write() in Python?

Tags: python, file, csv

As I was learning about opening files in Python I came across both .write and .DictWriter. The Files section was split into 3 sections: Regular files, CSV files, and JSON files.

My question is: Can we use .write() in a CSV file and .DictWriter() in a regular txt file?

From my notes I have:

```
#Writing a New File

with open('generated_file.txt', 'w') as gen_file:
  gen_file.write("What an incredible file!")
```

using .write() for a regular txt file

and:

```
#Writing a CSV File

big_list = [{'name': 'Fredrick Stein', 'userid': 6712359021, 'is_admin': False}, {'name': 'Wiltmore Denis', 'userid': 2525942, 'is_admin': False}, {'name': 'Greely Plonk', 'userid': 15890235, 'is_admin': False}, {'name': 'Dendris Stulo', 'userid': 572189563, 'is_admin': True}] 
#In our code above we had a set of dictionaries with the same keys for each, a prime candidate for a CSV.

import csv
#We import the csv library,

with open('output.csv', 'w') as output_csv:
#and then open a new CSV file in write-mode by passing the 'w' argument to the open() function.

  fields = ['name', 'userid', 'is_admin']
#We then define the fields we’re going to be using into a variable called fields.

  output_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_csv, fieldnames=fields)
#We then instantiate our CSV writer object and pass two arguments. 
#The first is output_csv, the file handler object. 
#The second is our list of fields fields which we pass to the keyword parameter fieldnames.

  output_writer.writeheader()
#Now that we’ve instantiated our CSV file writer, we can start adding lines to the file itself! 
#First we want the headers, so we call .writeheader() on the writer object. 
#This writes all the fields passed to fieldnames as the first row in our file.

  for item in big_list:
#Then we iterate through our big_list of data. 
#Each item in big_list is a dictionary with each field in fields as the keys.

    output_writer.writerow(item)
#We call output_writer.writerow() with the item dictionaries which writes each line to the CSV file.
```

using .DictWriter() for a CSV file

Can we use these write methods interchangeably in txt, and csv files?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: Can we use .write() in a CSV file and .DictWriter() in a regular txt file?

Not really.

Technically a CSV file is still a file so you could manipulate it as just that, though you should not do so as it won't properly handle issues like escaping.

csv.writer and csv.DictWriter are specialised to transforms rows (respectively lists and dicts) into CSV data, properly escaped according to the *dialect*. So it doesn't make sense to use them for non-CSV files, though CSV are, technically, "regular txt file" in the sense that they're just weirdly formatted text.

Comment: Thanks Masklinn, what if we use with open() would that take care of any escaping issues? What about using the regular .write() in a csv file, would it make sense to do so?

Comment: No and not really. `open` (and its `write` method) have no insight as to the file's structure, you can use them to write anything you want to the file, with no regard for the purported structural constraints of whatever format the file is *supposed* to be. So technically you can use bare `open()` and `write()` calls but then you'll have to take care of all the quoting and escaping yourself.